# Browser back button is not working properly, I am pressing back in same component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a recommended section on my page which if I select, is working properly. But while using browser back button I can see the URL is getting changed but the page is not going according to the previous page. Both pages are getting overwritten. My code recommended section has different components and the main section has different components of my angular project.

Note: When the recommended section is clicked the page is reloading.

Current URL: `http://localhost:8080/project/slidercontent/2`

After hitting back button URL: `http://localhost:8080/pwa/slidercontent/0`

Comment: that is because that point towards same component it won't load

Comment: You can provide more clarity by adding few lines of code and images/image links if required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used "replaceUrl:true" .When true, navigates while replacing the current state in history.

this.router.navigate(['/villa', this.villaName_param], {
        queryParams: {
         ..........,
         ..........,
         ..........
        }, replaceUrl: true
      })

for more information about [replaceState](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replaceState) you can refer